# Returning data from an angular factory, data is populated after object is returned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, promise

I'm having a bit of trouble with my Angular factory. It returns data correctly 
 but in the chrome console when I try to log it, it's empty initially and chrome shows a message beside my object - `object value at left was snapshotted when logged`. When I expand my object everything is there. If I try to loop through the returned data, I get an undefined error.

I'm pretty sure this is promise territory, but I'm not sure how I would go about it. I just want to be able to loop through process the data returned from this factory in my controller. My code is below, any insights would be appreciated.

```
   angular.module('myMap').factory('mapSorter', function($http) {
      x2js = new X2JS(),
      data = {
        styles: [],
        layers: []
      };
      return {
        //pass in array of objects with url property
        processMapData : function(kmls) {
        //loop through each object
          angular.forEach(kmls, function(kml) {
            $http.get(kml.url).then(function(response) {
              //push properties from response into data object
              data.styles = data.styles.concat(x2js.xml_str2json(response.data).kml.Document.Style)
              data.layers.push(x2js.xml_str2json(response.data).kml.Document.Placemark)
            })
          })
          return(data);
        }
    }
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: where are you console.log 'in your data? $http.get request are asynchronous, so you must wait for your data to arrive before returning it, and printing it in the console

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm doing this in my controller:
`mapData = mapSorter.processMapData($scope.kmlLayers);
console.log(mapData)`

Where ($scope.kmlLayers) is my object that I'm passing into the processMapData function.

Comment: I guess I just need a way to figure out when all my data is returned, either before it is returned from the factory or after the object is received from the controller.

Comment: you should check @maddockst response. You need to push into an array all the promises returned from $http.get function, and use $q.all to wait for them. After that, you can access them and log them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider having a look at `$q.all`. It accepts an array of promises and will resolve once all promises have resolved. You'll be able to do something like this:

```
$q.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values){
    console.log(values[0]) // promise1 value
    console.log(values[1]) // promise2 value
    console.log(values[2]) // promise3 value
});
```

All you will have to do is push each promise into an array and then return `$q.all(array)`. You'll then be able to call `then` within your controller and get all your responses.

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Hi @maddockst, thanks for the response. This helps a lot and I think I'm close. Some of my data is being returned, but some of it isn't. I think it's the way my code is structured, any chance you can help me out? I've commented the problem area.
http://pastebin.com/cQfU32wH Thanks :)

Comment: As far as I can see, you're return / console is outside of the `$q.all()` and as such, may not have finished building your object just yet. However, you're returning data inside `$q.all()` which will create a new promise for you. So, if you return the `$q.all()` then in your controller you'll be able to do a call to `then` on the `processMapData` which will have your data object passed into your callback. Does this make sense?

Comment: I think that did the trick. I'm getting all the data in my controller now, thank you :)